# Better trigonometrical inequalities for $\zeta(s)$?

Tags: riemann-zeta-function, trigonometric-sums, trigonometric-polynomials

The inequality $$3 + 4 \cos \theta + \cos 2 \theta \geq 0$$ plays a key role in the proof of the classical zero-free region of the Riemann zeta function. Are there other inequalities of the form
$$\sum_{i=0}^k a_i \cos b_i \theta \geq 0,\;\;\;\;\;a_\geq 0$$
such that $a_{i_0} = \sum_{i\ne i_0} a_i$ for some $0\leq i_0\leq k$ and $a_{0} < \frac{3}{4} a_{i_0}$, $b_0=0$?

Comment: $1+\cos \theta \ge 0$;  $99+100 \cos \theta +\cos 2\theta \ge 0$; $98+100\cos \theta +\cos (2\theta) + \cos (4\theta) \ge 0$ (didn't check the last one, but surely it's correct).  Depends on what you're after?  For zero free regions this is not the relevant criterion (one coefficient being sum of the others) -- presumably you've already looked at Kadiri, Stechkin ...

Comment: I should have added that $a_0<a_{i_0}$. What would be useful would be $a_0< 3 a_{i_0}/4$, actually.

Comment: apologies, but I do not understand what difference the condition you added makes; in the example I gave in the answer box I have $k=i_0=3$, $a_0,a_1,a_2=1,2,3$, $b_0,b_1,b_2=1,2,3$, and $a_{3}=6$, $b_3=0$, so $a_0=1<3a_{i_0}/4=9/2$.

Comment: I should have said $b_0=0$.

Comment: @Lucia: what I have in mind is actually just to improve explicit bounds on $1/\zeta(\sigma+it)$ for $\sigma>1$ (so as to improve explicit bounds on $1/\zeta(1+it)$). Or would a better zero-free region necessarily follow from an inequality such as the one I request?

Comment: I would like to add a reference if it is useful for you (I do not know if it is relevant/useful for this post, because I am not a professional mathematician). I know that there is a section that maybe you know (first paragraph of section 5) of the paper by Kevin Ford, *Zero-free Regions for the Riemann Zeta Function*, Number Theory for the Millenium II, A K Peters (2002). Maybe the author have some information in his homepage. Thus I don't know if my comment is relevant for your question/work, isn't required a response.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming the $b_i$ are all distinct (or at least non-zero for $i \neq 0$), this is not possible.  (Otherwise there are trivial examples, e.g. $1 + 2 \cos(0 \theta)+ \cos(0 \theta) \geq 0$ or $1 + 4 \cos \theta + \cos(2\theta) + 2 \cos(0 \theta) \geq 0$.)

Suppose that $\sum_{i=0}^k a_i \cos b_i \theta \geq 0$.  Since $a_{i_0} = \sum_{i \neq i_0} a_i$, this implies that whenever $\cos b_{i_0} \theta = -1$, one must have $\cos b_i \theta = +1$ for all other $i$.  In particular, the other $b_i$ must be integer multiples of $2b_{i_0}$.  We now have

$$ a_0 + a_{i_0} \cos b_{i_0} \theta + \sum_{i \neq 0, i_0} a_i \cos b_i\theta \geq 0$$

with the $b_i$ in the sum nonzero integer multiples of $2b_{i_0}$.  Performing a Taylor expansion around $\theta = \pi / b_{i_0}$ to second order, we conclude that

$$ - a_{i_0} \frac{b_{i_0}^2}{2} + \sum_{i \neq 0, i_0} a_i \frac{b_i^2}{2} \geq 0$$

and hence (since $b_i^2 \geq 4 b_{i_0}^2$ and $b_{i_0} \neq 0$)

$$ \sum_{i \neq 0, i_0} a_i \leq \frac{1}{4} a_{i_0}$$

or equivalently

$$ a_0 \geq \frac{3}{4} a_{i_0}.$$

Thus one cannot have $a_0 < \frac{3}{4} a_{i_0}$.  This argument also shows that up to rescaling and other trivial rearrangements, Mertens' inequality $3 + 4 \cos(\theta)+\cos(2\theta) \geq 0$ is the unique inequality that attains $a_0 = \frac{3}{4} a_{i_0}$.

At a more metamathematical level, if there were a variant of Mertens' trigonometric inequality that gave superior numerical results towards the classical zero free region, I would imagine that this would already have been noticed by now. :-)

Comment: Nice. I had a different and much more modest possible application in mind, but, as I made my question more precise, I started seeing that it could give a numerically better zero-free region (and hence the answer was almost certainly "no", for meta-mathematical reasons, as you put it).

Answer (score 5):

<sub>this is an answer to the question as originally posed, without the additional conditions on $a_0$ and $b_0$</sub>

for example, 
$$6+\cos \theta+2 \cos 2 \theta+3 \cos 3 \theta\geq 0,$$
or more generally 
$$\tfrac{1}{2}k(k+1)+\sum_{n=1}^k n \cos n\theta\geq 0.$$